# openpyxl always outputs the length of the longest column when you use len(sheet[column_a]) even if column_a is not the longest

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

in openpyxl, when I try to find out the length of a specific column, I get the length of the longest column . how do I determine the length of a certain column

````
```python
from openpyxl import load_workbook
file_name = "spreadsheet.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(file_name)
sheet = wb.active #grab the first active sheet
print("length of column A is", len(sheet["A"])) # expected answer 1
print("length of column B is", len(sheet["B"])) # expected answer 3
print("length of column C is", len(sheet["C"])) # expected answer 2
```
````

here is the output of the code

````
```output
length of column A is 3
length of column B is 3
length of column C is 3
```
````

[this is the excel spreadsheet I used.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgO9q.png)

if openpyxl doesn't have a feature to do this, is there any other librarry that can be used?

Comment: Read the Entire Column as list and find its length, then it will give you the correct answer

Comment: Please don't post images of your code, instead, try pasting the code directly in here, formatted within codeblocks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find the last row in a column using openpyxl normal workbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541692/how-to-find-the-last-row-in-a-column-using-openpyxl-normal-workbook)