# the way to input date in excel file with python openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I want to input date of text and sum function in excel file. The excel file content is changed everyday, so I don't know which row is right position in excel file.

The image of the excel file is the output that I want to do. The image is as followed.
[image]

In this excel file, I need to input text in A29, but the excel amount is changed next time.
This is the coding what I did. If you have any idea, please let me know that.

This is the coding that I did as followed.

```
ws['ws.max_row + 9',1] = '합계'
```

OR

```
z = ws.cell(row=ws.max_row + 9, column=1).value
```

Both have error occurred.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to enter a value on the 9th row after the last row in an excel sheet using openpyxl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write to a row 9 rows after the last row in the excel sheet. You can get the last row using `ws.max_row` as you have done and add 9 to it.

You are on the right track. When accessing a cell using `ws[]` you need to pass a cell identifier as used in Excel like - `ws['A1']`
If you need to access a cell using row and column numbers, you may do so with the `ws.cell()` function as you have in the second example.
you only need to interchange RHS and LHS in your code snippet.

The below code should achieve what you need

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(filename='sample.xlsx')
ws = wb.active
last_row = ws.max_row
ws.cell(row=last_row + 9, column=1).value = 'New Value'
wb.save(filename='sample.xlsx')
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33543305/5236575

Comment: It was great! I try to do it, and it works. Thank you for your help.