# Python 3.5.2 , openpyxl v 2.4.1 ,get_highest_row() , AttributeError

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl, attributeerror

I'm new to Python,while I'm facing a problem with opening an Excel file with `openpyxl` Module.I'm Running `openpyxl` V2.4.1 on `Python 3.5.2` on Windows.Here is a small part of my Code.I'm getting the Following Error.

This is the Error I'm getting:

[image]

Please Help me to Solve this,finding a Way to get Maximum number of Rows and Columns in a Sheet.

If I have to change my `openpyxl` Module version,please describe!

Thanks in advance.

```
WorkBook = openpyxl.load_workbook("G:\\Python_Created\\DS.xlsx")
#I have a Sheet named "Original" in my Excell Workbook
Sheet = WorkBook.get_sheet_by_name("Original")
Sheet.get_highest_row()
```

Comment: I think there is no such attribute in the Latest Version of `openpyxl`.Using `SheetObj.max_row` and `SheetObj.max_column` will serve the same purpose.They will Return the Highest Number of Rows and Columns respectively.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [enigmas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13377793/is-it-possible-to-get-an-excel-documents-row-count-without-loading-the-entire-d) answer

```
wb = load_workbook(path, use_iterators=True)
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]

row_count = sheet.max_row
column_count = sheet.max_column
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that method is depreciated,
In the newer version of openpyxl library
Visit https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/
you can use this method to get the Row Count and Column count

```
#to get the row count
sheet.max_row
#to get the column count
sheet.max_column
```