# Read the last column from an Excel file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

It's like [how to read certain columns from Excel using Pandas - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33655127/6666231) but a little bit more complicated.

Say I have an Excel file called "foo.xlsx" and it grows over time - a new column will be appended on the right every month. However, when I read it, I need only the first two and the last columns. I expected `usecols` parameter can solve this problem so I went `df = pd.read_excel("foo.xlsx", usecols=[0, 1, -1])` but it gives me only the first two columns.

My workaround turns out to be:

```
df = pd.read_excel("foo.xlsx")
df = df[df.columns[[0, 1, -1]]]
```

But it needs reading the whole file every time. Is there any way that I can get my desired data frame while reading the file? Thanks.

Comment: @Nihal Could you please elaborate your points? `pandas` does support reading the file with specified columns, but I am asking how to always get the last one.

Comment: I suppose specifying the `usecols` argument won't save a lot of time because `read_excel` always reads the whole sheet. `usecols` just skips the rest after heaving read everything and will only accelerate parsing .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to do this (see my comment above) you could to this:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
ncols = xl.book.sheets()[0].ncols
df = xl.parse(0, usecols=[0, 1, ncols-1])
```

This solution won't read the excel file twice.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, doesn't `xl.book.sheets()[0].ncols` need to read the whole Excel file to get the answer? I checked [ExcelFile Vs. read_excel in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49991054/6666231) and I wonder how this solution can be better.

Comment: Yes, it has to read the whole file. But the following parse command doesn't have to id again. So overall not much has been won, but nothing is done twice (in contrast to jezreal's answer)

Answer (score 1):

One idea is get [column count](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13377793) and pass to `usecols`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = "file.xlsx"

wb = load_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
column_count = sheet.max_column
print (column_count)
```

Or read only first row of file:

```
column_count  = len(pd.read_excel(path, nrows=0).columns)
```

---

```
df = pd.read_excel(path, usecols=[0, 1, column_count-1])
print (df)
```

Comment: This is suboptimal because the excel file will be read twice which is very time consuming for big files.

Answer (score -1):

You can use df.head() and df.tail() to read the first 2 and last line. For example:

```
df = pd.read_excel("foo.xlsx", sheet_name='ABC')
#print the first 2 column
print(df.head(2))
#print the last column
print(df.tail(1))
```

EDIT: Oops the above code reads rows and not columns. Yes, you have to read the file everytime. I don't think there's an option to read partial file.

For reading column maybe you can do something like this

```
df['Column Name'][index]
```

Comment: Your answer provides rows, not columns. Also, it cannot prevent reading the whole file while the file is getting larger over time.