# Append data in New Column in excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, append

I have to Run this code everyday and store dataframe in new columns
How to Store the data frame to next column automatically without specifying the column number in excel file using Python Here dx stores the day of month i.e "09-11-2022" dx=9 so the data gets stored in column 9 but there will be gaps if i run it after some time like if dx=22 the columns between 9-22 will be empty So how to store data to next new column without specifying the startcol

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({today:mob})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({today:dtop})

writer=pd.ExcelWriter('Pagespeed.xlsx',mode='a',engine="openpyxl",
       if_sheet_exists='overlay')

df1.to_excel(writer, index=False,sheet_name='Mobile',startcol=dx)

df2.to_excel(writer,index=False,sheet_name='Desktop',startcol=dx)

writer.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54801584/10703543) to get the max populated column in the excel file.

Then use `startcol = max_column + 1` to write to the next empty column

Comment: max_column not defined it says

Comment: @Abhishek Raina Did you try this code? from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = "Pagespeed.xslx"

wb = load_workbook(path)
sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
max_column = sheet.max_column